# problem connect ipad to ubuntu desktop with tigervnc

Tags: 20.04, vnc

I have installed tigervnc in Ubuntu 20.04.4 but it does not work well.

My unit file is the following one (I want to run like as service):
(/etc/systemd/system/vncserver.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 309 Mar 17 22:00 vncserver.service)

```
[Unit]
Description=TightVNC server
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
PAMName=login
PIDFile=/root/.vnc/%H:1.pid
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1 > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I run the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl start vncserver.service
Job for vncserver.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status vncserver.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When I check it the following message appears:

**sudo systemctl status vncserver.service**

```
● vncserver.service - TightVNC server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-03-18 08:54:17 UTC; 2min 7s ago
    Process: 40993 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1 > /dev/null 2>&1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 40999 ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)

Mar 18 08:54:17 ubuntu vncserver[41110]:  vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on local interface(s), port 5901
Mar 18 08:54:17 ubuntu vncserver[41110]:  vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
Mar 18 08:54:17 ubuntu vncserver[41110]: X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Mar 18 08:54:17 ubuntu vncserver[41110]: Fri Mar 18 08:54:16 2022
Mar 18 08:54:17 ubuntu vncserver[41110]:  ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
Mar 18 08:54:17 ubuntu vncserver[41110]:  ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)
Mar 18 08:54:17 ubuntu vncserver[41110]: Killing Xtigervnc process ID 41008... which seems to be deadlocked. Using SIGKILL!
Mar 18 08:54:17 ubuntu systemd[1]: vncserver.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
Mar 18 08:54:17 ubuntu systemd[1]: vncserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 18 08:54:17 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start TightVNC server.
```

I try to access with the VNC Viewer app (from iPad) and the following error message appears:

[image: VNC Viewer]

[image: Error message]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do? The title does not seem to apply to the question as there is nothing in the question about an iPad.

Comment: sorry, I have inserted two snapshots about VNC Viewer from ipad